# How to set timeout parameter in the network image in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, http, dart, timeout

I'm trying to load a huge size image from network using photoview library using the following code

```
PhotoView(
        minScale:
        PhotoViewComputedScale.contained *
              0.8,
        maxScale:
        PhotoViewComputedScale.contained *
              1.8,
        backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white),
        enableRotation: false,
        imageProvider:
        NetworkImage(widget
              .url,),
      )
```

I know that there is known libraries that provide an imageProvider such as cachednetworkimage but that library doesn't have that feature yet as described here

https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/465

my question is:
Is there any way to change the time-out by adding headers to `NetworkImage` or is there any another library that provider a customizable `imageProvider` which can enable us to change the time-out

Comment: Did you try to add "Keep-Alive":{ timeout=5,}``` to header ?

Comment: the number 5 here indicate 5 seconds or 5 milliseconds ...plus I don't know what is the correct syntax of adding headers to networkImage object

Comment: In seconds, and ```NetworkProvider``` has ```headers``` parameter, just call it that way ```headers:{"Keep-Alive":"timeout=5"}

Comment: it didn't work..I've added 60 as a timeout but it stop download after 20 seconds

Comment: The server returned an error, the timeout is a timer to wait for the server before stopping automatically

Comment: no the server return the image perfectly when using a higher bandwidth ..I believe there is another way to change the timeout from flutter side..BTW you could test the server using this image url example "in case you want to use another platform to test the timeout"

Comment: this is the image url: http://www.tarjemly-live.com/admin/uploads/uploads_tr_images/16217836089248111.jpeg,

Comment: I investigate in the source code of ```NetworkProvider``` ,they are using ```HttpClient``` but the ```timeout``` parameter is not set so it can't be done directly using ```NetworkProvider```